# Graficar media, SD e intervalo de confianza con datos ordenados por fila

Tags: r

Tengo un conjunto de datos [con este formato](https://www.dropbox.com/s/adkty68rwcyzq5p/data_95.csv?dl=0). ¿Cómo puedo representar la media, Desviación Estandar y el intervalo de confianza 95% de las replicaciones 1 a 5 en el eje-y, y N en el eje-x?

El código que he utilizado para calcular CI en el pasado es este, pero no sé cómo adaptarlo a los nuevos datos.

```
data %>%
  summarise(mean = mean(y), 
            desvio = sd(y),                             
            error_est = desvio / sqrt(n()),             
            intervalo_sup = mean + (2*error_est),       
            intervalo_inf = mean - (2*error_est)) %>%  
  ggplot(aes(x = N, y = mean)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = intervalo_sup,
  ymin = intervalo_inf)
```

Comment: ¡Hola @prying! ¿Podrías explicar un poco más sobre los datos? ¿Qué representa cada fila? Veo muchos 0 y no termino de comprender bien a qué hacen referencia, pensaba en un principio que cada columna era una simulación, pero dudo que sea así.

Comment: Hola @R18 cada fila son datos de un día. Cada día se hacen 5 replicacones, Rep 1 a 5. Por lo tanto, cada día tenemos una media. ¿Cómo puedo calcular y graficar la media con CI y SD a lo largo de los días?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En primer lugar, para el calculo de los intervalos de confianza voy a usar las manera más simple, haciendo una regresión lineal y calculando los intervalos sobre ésta (Ver [fuente](https://bookdown.org/logan_kelly/r_practice/p09.html))

```
ci <- function(x, level=0.95, bound=1) {
  l.model <- lm(x ~ 1, list(x))
  as.vector(confint(l.model, level=level))[bound]
}
```

Leemos tus datos:

```
data <- read.csv('~/Descargas/data_95.csv', check.names = FALSE)
```

Lo primero que hago es a) ignorar la columna `Mean`, vamos a volver a calcularla, b) expandir los 5 valores de `Repl` de forma vertical c) con esta estructura larga, podremos agrupar y sumarisar para obtener los coeficientes buscados de manera sencilla:

```
data %>%
  select(-Mean) %>% 
  pivot_longer(c(-N)) %>% 
  group_by(N) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(value), 
            desvio = sd(value),                             
            error_est = desvio / sqrt(n()),             
            intervalo_sup = ci(value, bound = 2),       
            intervalo_inf = ci(value, bound = 1),
            .groups="keep") -> plot_data

plot_data

# A tibble: 80 × 6
# Groups:   N [80]
       N  mean desvio error_est intervalo_sup intervalo_inf
   <int> <dbl>  <dbl>     <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
 1     1   0      0         0             0            0   
 2     2   0      0         0             0            0   
 3     3  40.8   25.7      11.5          72.7          8.91
 4     4 208.    23.9      10.7         238.         179.  
 5     5 195     82.9      37.1         298.          92.0 
 6     6 181.   102.       45.4         307.          55.1 
 7     7 156     89.6      40.1         267.          44.8 
 8     8 149.    84.5      37.8         254.          43.9 
 9     9 101.    63.5      28.4         180.          22.6 
10    10 125.    74.9      33.5         218.          31.8 
# … with 70 more rows
```

Por último, puedes graficar la media y los intervalos haciendo algo así:

```
plot_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=N, y=mean)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = intervalo_sup, ymin = intervalo_inf)) +
  geom_point(colour="blue")
```

Reultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

¡Hola @pyring!

A continuación escribo el código para la obtención (un tanto rudimentaria, el gráfico básico que sale con ggplot2) del gráfico que solicitas

```
# Calcular la media y la desviación típica
  # Media (ya calculada, en tu caso es $Media)
    datos$mean <- apply(datos[,-c(1,2)],1,mean)
  # Desviación típica    
    datos$sd <- apply(datos[,-c(1,2)],1,sd)

# NOTA: la función apply, aplica a "datos" (expecto las columnas 1 y 2, por eso el -c(1,2)) por fila (de ahí el 1), la función sd (desviación típica)        


# Intervalo de confianza
    # Cota inferior
      datos$cota_inf <- datos$mean - 2*datos$sd/sqrt(5)
    # Cota superior
      datos$cota_sup <- datos$mean + 2*datos$sd/sqrt(5)

# Representación gráfica      
  ggplot(datos, aes(x=N, y=mean)) +
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymax = cota_sup, ymin = cota_inf))
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Una pregunta. ¿Cómo estás calculando la desviación estandar aquí? Se supone que la desviación estandar de cada día se debe calcular a partir de la desviación de las 5 replicaciones de cada día? No veo muy bien cómo está implementado eso en el código.

Comment: La función `sd` calcula la desviación típica de los valores.

Comment: Ya, pero qué valores está considerando este código para computar sd. ¿Las columnas Repl. 1 a Repl. 5?

Comment: Así es, he incluido una aclaración sobre la función apply, explicando que se ejecuta por fila al poner el 1.